# Can Server Socket and multiple clients run on a single host?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Can we run multiple clients & 1 server on a single machine?
Let's say I have a server class (thread for multiple connections) and a client class as well. I want to run at least 2 clients at the same time but they have separate chat window(Server to client but not Group chat). Is it Possible?
I have this code

```
public void server(){
    ss = new ServerSocket(port);

    chatprocess cp = new chatprocess(socket);// accept connection inside and input/output as well
}

public client(){
    socket = new socket("localhost",port);
    clientprocess(); //i/o inside
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Okay, I have this abstract in my mind. That in order to do that I have to create a separate chat window for server as well. I mean, if client A will connect, so only 1 chat window for server. But if client B is connected aswell while A is still up so it will be another chat window for server? Am I right? or no?

Comment: What do you call "chat window for server" ?

Comment: @Berger Area where chat is processed i.e Textarea+textfield+btn for server.

Comment: The server side ensures communication between clients, it doesn't really have a "chat window". You may see an example here (without GUI but you probably already have a GUI part) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853189/multithreaded-client-server-chat-application-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In order to do that you must create a thread assigned for each client. There are a lot of examples here in SO.